# SED command: won't insert the string I want

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell, sed

I want to write the following code into the "sed -i" command.

I'm trying the following command:

```
sed -i '2s/^/if \(\$_SERVER[\"REQUEST_URI\"\] == \'/site/template.php\'\) \{\$name=mysql_result\(\$result,\$i+2,\"Name\"\);\$auth=mysql_result\(\$result,\$i+2,\"Author\"\);\$date=mysql_result\(\$result,\$i+2,\"Date\"\);body=mysql_result\(\$result,\$i+2,\"Content\"\);\}\n' ../site/written.php
```

This is the piece of code:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] == '/site/template.php') {
        $name=mysql_result($result,$i+1,"Name");
        $auth=mysql_result($result,$i+1,"Author");
        $date=mysql_result($result,$i+1,"Date");
        $body=mysql_result($result,$i+1,"Content");
}
```

When I do this, it won't insert and get a "> " thing in the shell.

So how should I actually do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put it in double quotes, to get a first result.

More details: Escape the `/` in `/site/template` too.  Also escape `\\n` in `\n`.  Add `/` to end finalize search expression.

```
sed -i "2s/^/if \(\$_SERVER[\"REQUEST_URI\"\] == \'\/site\/template.php\'\) \{\$name=mysql_result\(\$result,\$i+2,\"Name\"\);\$auth=mysql_result\(\$result,\$i+2,\"Author\"\);\$date=mysql_result\(\$result,\$i+2,\"Date\"\);body=mysql_result\(\$result,\$i+2,\"Content\"\);\}\\n/" ../site/written.php
```

Answer (score 0):

there is more errors - version below corrects them

```
sed -i "s/^/if \(\$\_SERVER[\"REQUEST_URI\"\] == \"\/site\/template.php\"\) \{\n\t\$name=mysql_result(\$result,\$i+1,\"Name\");\n\t\$auth=mysql_result(\$result,\$i+1,\"Author\");\n\t\$date=mysql_result(\$result,\$i+1,\"Date\");\n\t\$body=mysql_result(\$result,\$i+1,\"Content\");\n}\n/" ../site/written.php
```